# How to handle Port Mapping while running Redis-Cluster using Spring-Data-Redis and Jedis

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-redis

When I am running a Redis Cluster inside a test container with image as `grokzen/redis-cluster:6.0.7`
I am not able to connect to the Redis Cluster.
I faced the similar problem when I was using Spring-Data-Redis with Lettuce and the solution is well explained in this [blog](https://medium.com/@truongbui95/setting-up-a-local-redis-cluster-using-testcontainers-in-spring-boot-7e9b157c980a) an [githubRepo](https://github.com/Hixon10/spring-redis-cluster-testcontainers).

I am looking for the same kind of support in Spring-Data-Redis with Jedis.
Please suggest if you have any solution for this.

**NOTE:** This is only require for the Redis Running in TestContainers, it works with the default configuration with actual Redis cluster

I am looking for SocketResolver funtionality in Spring-Data-Redis for Jedis.
I could see one JedisSocketFactory class in Jedis Lib But not sure how Sprng-Data-Redis has given a support for that.